# In cypress check the correction of the same word a few times

Tags: cypress

I have a page where I have to check the correction of the german written word "Smartcard". From time to time I am finding mistakes in this word. So my goal is to write a test in cypress that will check in the whole page all words 'Smartcard' that is might written 'Smart card' or 'Smart Card' or 'smartcard' or 'Smart-card'.
I tried to do it with .contains(), but it usually takes only the first element.
I will appreciate any suggestions.

'''const blacklist = ['Smartcard', 'Smart-card', 'Smart Card', 'Smart cards', 'Smart-cards', 'Smart Cards']

```
    blacklist.forEach((item) => {
      cy.findByText(item).should("not.exist");
    });
```

'''

Tried using the black list, but for some reason it doesn't see what is inside black list. Or does anyone knows how .findByText works?

Comment: Can you supply us with the code of your implementation? It is easier to talk about the directly code than about assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the all the words by matching it against a regex. Based on your example, I have created a regex as `/smart.*card/i` that will accept the following words - Smartcard, Smart card, Smart Card, smartcard, Smart-card

[image: regex result]

You cypress code should be something like:

```
cy.get('selector').each(($el) => {
    const text = $el.text()
    expect(text).to.match(/smart.*card/i)
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It is a great option to do it.
But do I understand right, that I have to add each location where the potentially wrong word could be written?
And do u know if there is any other possibility to check it on the whole page, without mentioning each location?